# Excepcion, al habilitar el Scanner en el dispositivo Zebra EMDK Android

Tags: android, scanner, qrcode, código-de-barras, zebra

Estoy realizando una app para el dispositivo Zebra MC3300x, modelo MC330L, con el API 30 de Android, me aparece el siguiente error cuando inicializo el escaner de la PDA:

***Cannot enable scanner and is already in use***

El mensaje me aparece en un toast.

Activity Principal: ScannerEjempActivity.

```
public class ScannerEjempActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EMDKManager.EMDKListener, Scanner.StatusListener, Scanner.DataListener {

private static Context context;
private static Activity activity;

private Intent sendIntent;
private IntentFilter receiverFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver scanReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner_ejemp);
    context = this;
    activity = this;
    initScanner();
}

private void initScanner(){
    try {
        EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(getApplicationContext(), this);
        if (results.statusCode!=   EMDKResults.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS) {
            UtilScanZebra.errorSoud(context);
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Error de conexion Scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        ActiveScan.desactiveScan(this);
        sendIntent = new Intent("nlscan.action.SCANNER_TRIG");
        sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
        scanReceiver = getScanReceiver();
        receiverFilter = new IntentFilter("nlscan.action.SCANNER_RESULT");
        ActiveScan.desactiveScan(this);
        registerReceiver(scanReceiver, receiverFilter);
        ActiveScan.activeScan(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onOpened(EMDKManager emdkManager) {
    UtilScanZebra.emdkManager =  emdkManager;
    UtilScanZebra.initBarcodeManager(activity, context);
    UtilScanZebra.initScanner(activity,context);
}

@Override
public void onClosed() {
    if ( UtilScanZebra.emdkManager != null) {
        UtilScanZebra.emdkManager.release();
        UtilScanZebra.emdkManager = null;
    }
    UtilScanZebra.errorSoud(context);
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Cerrado inesperadamente! Cierre y reinicie la aplicación..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {
    AsyncDataUpdate asyncStatusUpdate = new AsyncDataUpdate(context, activity, scanDataCollection, "ScannerEjempActivity");
    asyncStatusUpdate.execute();
}

@Override
public void onStatus(StatusData statusData) {
    AsyncStatusUpdate asyncStatusUpdate = new AsyncStatusUpdate(context, activity, statusData);
    asyncStatusUpdate.execute();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (UtilScanZebra.emdkManager != null) {
        UtilScanZebra.emdkManager.release();
        UtilScanZebra.emdkManager= null;
    }
}

public static void info(String code){
    Toast.makeText(activity, code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private BroadcastReceiver getScanReceiver() {
    return new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_STATE").equals("ok")) {
                processScancode(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_BARCODE1"));
            }
        }
    };
}

private void processScancode(String scancode) {
    info(scancode);
}

}
```

Clase Auxiliar: AsyncDataUpdate

```
public class AsyncDataUpdate extends AsyncTask<ScanDataCollection,Void,String> {
private static Context context;
private static Activity activity;
private static ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection;
private static String viewActive;

public AsyncDataUpdate(Context context, Activity activity, ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection, String viewActive) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.scanDataCollection = scanDataCollection;
    this.viewActive = viewActive;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(ScanDataCollection... params) {
    String statusStr = "";
    if ((scanDataCollection != null) && (scanDataCollection.getResult() == ScannerResults.SUCCESS)) {
        ArrayList<ScanDataCollection.ScanData> scanData = scanDataCollection.getScanData();
        for(ScanDataCollection.ScanData data : scanData) {
            statusStr = data.getData();
        }
    }
    return statusStr;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String statusStr) {
    if(viewActive.equals("ScannerEjempActivity")) {
        ScannerEjempActivity.info(statusStr);
    }
}
}
```

Al ejecutar el "Pistoleo" del escaner el sonido y la luz de ese funcionan sin problemas, pero no realiza ninguna accion, le he puesto puntos de interrupcion en todas partes, y no entra a ninguno.

Las aplicaciones de prueba que trae la PDA funcionan sin problemas.

Answer (score 1):

El EMDK solo puede interactuar con la app por una sola vez despues que la aplicacion ha  llamado al EMDK. Si ese es el caso, lo recomendable seria entonces que cierres el EMDK antes que hagas un nuevo llamado de esa u otra aplicacion. Las aplicaciones de prueba cierran el EMDK cuando se hace un onPause() lo cual es lo que usted esta observando que trabaja cuando usted las corre.